# "Expanding" probability mass function in terms of moments

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a positive and **deiscrete** random variable $n$, and a corresponding probability mass function $P(n)$. Suppose we have the numerical values of all the moments $E[n^k]$ and central moments $E[(n-E[n])^k]$. Is there a way to express or approximate $P(n)$ in terms of the moments?

If the random variable is a continuous one, I can use the moments to express the characteristic function, and do an inverse Fourier transform on the characteristic function to obtain the original random probability density function. I just need to correct formula to handle the discrete case. Most materials I came across only deal with the continuous case.

Comment: You don't need both the moments and the central moments; they can be expressed in terms of each other.

Comment: @joriki, You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For discrete random variable, we can use the Discrete-Time Fourier Transform to calculate the characteristic function:

$P(k)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}p_n\,e^{ikn}$

By definition, $P(k)=1+\sum_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{M_m}{m!}(ik)^m$, where $M_m$ is the $m$-th moment.

Once we have the characteristic function, we can get the original probability mass function by:

$p_n=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{2\pi}P(k)\,e^{-ikn}dk$